# Binary to Decimal Conversion in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program in java which takes decimal number as an int parameter and prints to the screen the binary equivalent of that decimal number ...
In short decimal to binary conversion using only int parameters ...

Solution will be much appreciated ... i have tried some steps but i am  not successful ..
Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you tried that did not work. Also mark this "homework" if it is your homework.

Comment: Could you maybe post in some code you already wrote so i can work on that?

Comment: i think you may be confused about the difference between an integer and a representation of an integer using a particular base.  An int in java is just an integer (it is not decimal or binary... just an integer).  Now internally java happens to represent ints as 2s complement binary numbers (and you can access that representation via bit operations) but in general you should think of an int as just an integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Integer.toString(input, 2);
```

OR

```
Integer.toBinaryString(input);
```

You might also want checkout:

```
Integer.toHexString
Integer.toOctalString
```

```
INPUT : 10    (decimal)
RESULT: 1010  (binary)
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

Or you can write program like this (modify it):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DecToBinary {

public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int broj;

  System.out.print("Enter number that you want to conver to binary: ");
  broj = input.nextInt();

  convert(broj);

}

 public static void convert(int a) {
  String obrnuti = "";
  while (a > 0) {
     int x = a % 2;
     obrnuti += x;
     a /= 2;
  }
  System.out.println(reverse(obrnuti));
}

public static String reverse(String a) {
   String novi = "";
   for (int i = a.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      char c = a.charAt(i);
      novi += c;
   }
   return novi;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

conversion from decimal to binary :

```
Integer.toBinaryString(Int_variable)
```

conversion from binary to decimal:

```
Integer.parseInt(string_binary_variable,2)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class BinaryToDecimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String binary = "110";
        System.out.println(binToDec(binary));
    }

    public static int binToDec(String binary){
        int decimal=0;
        for(int i=0;i<binary.length();i++){
            decimal = 2*decimal + Integer.parseInt("" + binary.charAt(i));
        }
        return decimal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class DecimalToBinary 
{    
    // 5 = 101

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int d2b = dec2Bin(5);
        System.out.println(d2b);
    }

    public static int dec2Bin(int num){
        int a = num;
        int binary=0;
        int i=1;
        while(a != 0){
            binary = binary+i*(a%2);
            a = a/2;
            i=i*10;
        }
        return binary;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add at least a little commentary to your answer to explain it.